# Passing data and add other data to it and pass it again

Tags: java, android

I have 3 activities , 
I sent data A from activity 1 to activity 2 .
I want to send data A + data B ( from second activity ) to activity 3 and show both data A and data B in a sentence in activity 3 . I do not know how to do this , how can i send data a and data b ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity A:

pass data to activity B

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext,ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("DataA",dataA);
i.startActivity(i);
```

retrive data in ActvityB

```
 String a;

Intent i = getIntent();
a= i.getStringExtra("DataA");
```

pass data in actvityc from ActivityB

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext,ActivityC.class);
 i.putExtra("DataA",a);
 i.putExtra("DataB",b);
 i.startActivity(i);
```

retrive data in ActvityC

```
String a,b;
 Intent i = getIntent();
 a= i.getStringExtra("DataA");
 b= i.getStringExtra("DataB");
```

Answer (score 0):

for send data from activity use :

```
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME", userName);
```

and get data in another activity :

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("USER_NAME");
```

if you wand send 2 data :

```
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME1", userName);
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME2", userName);
```

if you wand get 2 data :

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("USER_NAME1");
getIntent().getExtras().getString("USER_NAME2");
```